# Ограничение длины в TextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Я хочу ограничить `TextBox` по длине вводимых значений. Максимально 6.

1. В Свойстве `MaxLength` задал `6`.
2. В коде задал `tb_display.MaxLength = 6;`, но ничего не помогает.

Comment: Вы текст в TextBox вколачиваете руками, или программно устанавливаете свойство `Text`? В последнем случае ограничение работать не будет.

Comment: Да, забыл написать.У меня программа Домофон и ввод идет через Button, а их 12 штук. Только что проверил. На ввод с руки работает.А есть возможность сделать ограничение на программный ввод?

Comment: Разумеется есть. Проверяйте длину строки перед присвоением и, при необходимости, обрезайте. А то и вовсе делайте ваши 12 кнопок disabled, если длина текста в `TextBox` уже равна 6.

Comment: подключите обработчик к событию TextBox.TextChanged и проверяйте длину текста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ввода по шаблону можно использовать MaskedTextBox.

```
var f = new Form();
var t = new MaskedTextBox() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
t.Mask = "AAAAAA";  // не больше 6-ти цифр или букв
f.ShowDialog();
```

Значение для Mask берется из masking language -- [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms234064.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Сделал ограничение через

```
string s = tb_display.Text;
if (s.Count() == 6)
    {
         tb_display.Clear();
    }
```